# Future dates calculating incorrectly in FBProphet - make_future_dataframe method

Tags: facebook-prophet

I'm trying to do a weekly forecast in FBProphet for just 5 weeks ahead. The make_future_dataframe method doesn't seem to be working right....makes the correct one week intervals except for one week between jul 3 and Jul 5....every other interval is correct at 7 days or a week. Code and output below:

**INPUT DATAFRAME**

```
        ds        y
548 2010-01-01  3117
547 2010-01-08  2850
546 2010-01-15  2607
545 2010-01-22  2521
544 2010-01-29  2406
... ... ...
4   2020-06-05  2807
3   2020-06-12  2892
2   2020-06-19  3012
1   2020-06-26  3077
0   2020-07-03  3133
```

**CODE**

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=5, freq='W')
future.tail(9)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ds
545 2020-06-12
546 2020-06-19
547 2020-06-26
548 2020-07-03
549 2020-07-05
550 2020-07-12
551 2020-07-19
552 2020-07-26
553 2020-08-02
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a dataframe with the dates you need for predict method. utilizing the make_future_dataframe method is not necessary.